# Element is hiding below a overflow:auto element

Tags: css

Ok, I do understand that all child elements of an element `.wrapper` with `overflow:hidden` are naturally cut when leaving the `.wrapper`'s bounding box. But here I have only `overflow:auto` applied.

It's about the black drop down menu in the following examples:

Running as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/t13un62v/

Running with flaws: https://jsfiddle.net/t13un62v/1/

In the second example, the ONLY difference is the overflow:auto property of the parent element. What can I do to prevent the drop down hiding. I need overflow:auto on the parent.

Answer (score 1):

[`overflow: auto`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#valdef-overflow-auto) does clip overflow:

> This value indicates that the box’s content is clipped to the padding
>   box, but can be scrolled into view (and therefore the box is a [scroll
>   container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#scroll-container)).

Usually you would see scrollbars, but in your case the contents overflow towards the left edge, and browsers usually don't allow to scroll backwards.

If you want the scrollbar, you can use `direction: rtl` to allow to scroll towards the left (but not towards the right).

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  direction: rtl;
}
.item {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  direction: rtl;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  margin-left: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.item {
  direction: ltr;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #bbb;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #888;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #888;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
.item.open {
  background-color: #222;
}
.item > div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0
}
ul {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  z-index: 1000000;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">Item 920394234</div>
  <div class="item">Item 0394234</div>
  <div class="item">Item 394234</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9294234</div>
  <div class="item">Item 920234</div>
  <div class="item">Item 920394234</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9204</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9203</div>
  <div class="item">Item 994234</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9394234</div>
  <div class="item">Item 924</div>
  <div class="item open">Item Menu open
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>One</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">Item 159394234</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8139394234</div>
  <div class="item">Item s65494234</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1s23s19394234</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8416</div>
  <div class="item">Item 13</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Actually, I need the overlow for y-direction. Imagine a lare amount of `.item`s as in https://jsfiddle.net/t13un62v/2/
I had overlow-x:visible; overflow-y:auto before, but I learned that you can't use these in combination. What can I do? The dropdowns are bootstrap dropdowns and dynamic. I can of course change their css. I just made a static dd for the demo.

Comment: @Toni There is no workaround, except taking the element out-of-flow with `position: absolute`. But that will probably mess your layout.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get rid from the `.wrapper` so, you should add `absolute` to `.open`.

```
.item.open{
  position:absolute;
}
```

Look all code: https://jsfiddle.net/t13un62v/3/

Comment: Are you sure? The open div is now located in the top left corner and overlays the item there...